# How to solve an image overflow in Wordpress 3.5?

Tags: css, wordpress

When I am using Pamphlet/Banner type Image into the post in site, that image is not displaying properly. That shows Image overflow. How do I solve this?

[Live site](http://indieswebs.com/blog/magento-open-source-ecommerce-software-road-so-far/).

CSS that may be the problem:

```
#postbox p img
{
 border: 1px solid #5F9EB8;
 display: block;
 padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: For your future Questions, take this into account: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/185667).

Comment: @brasofilo Sorry I did not aware with this.... Next time I will take care of it... This wont happen again..... Sorry... and thanks for the Guidance.

Comment: Right now, for the Question to have value for future readers, you should post the previous CSS rule that was breaking the display ;)

Comment: you are telling me to put previous css code because of what i am getting error, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, because the "Live site" link will not show the original error anymore. A Question and an Answer should be autonomous == no need to go to other site to understand the problem and the solution.

Comment: @brasofilo okay I done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps giving the image a 100% width with an auto height might help?

```
#postbox p img {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #5F9EB8;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    height: auto;
}
```